# Jenkins auth plugin - where to store the script and how to pass parameters?

Tags: shell, jenkins

This is my first time dealing with Jenkins plugins - I apologize if it's too naive but I could not find an answer. Docs for this auth plugin, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Realm, say: "Each time the authentication is attemped (which is once per session), the specified script will be invoked". However, it does not say where to put the script or what to name it. Is there a standard directory for plugin-related scripts in Jenkins or do I need to do some configuration after I write this script? Also, how can I get user parameters, id and password, on a login attempt? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing the plugin, you should be able to choose the option **Authenticate via custom script** on Configure Global Security  | Security Realm and configure the script location as you can see in the following image.

[custom script realm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOCnj.png)